# Running nmap over vpn on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion fails

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, nmap, vpn-client

When connected to VPN (I have used OpenVPN and TunnelBear VPN service) nmap stops working.  Ping, nc and other network tools work however nmap doesnt.

When not running vpn, I get:

```
$ sudo nmap 8.8.8.8

    Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-12-07 15:38 CST
    Nmap scan report for google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8)
    Host is up (0.082s latency).
    Not shown: 998 filtered ports
    PORT    STATE  SERVICE
    53/tcp  open   domain
    113/tcp closed auth
```

When running over vpn, I get the following:

```
$ sudo nmap 8.8.8.8

    Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-12-07 15:08 CST
    Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
    Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.07 seconds
```

It is like nmap loses the traffic.  Doing tcpdump captures shows that the traffic is making it back to the box.

Any mac osx, OpenVPN or nmap experts have an idea?

I am using the latest macports nmap...

Comment: Have tried sudo nmap 8.8.8.8 -e tun0 and it fails.

Comment: Have verified that while on vpn, I can ping 8.8.8.8 and telnet 8.8.8.8 53 but nmap still shows the same as above

Comment: Please show us the routing table `sudo route -n`?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `nmap -e` option to the command line to specify the interface to use.  For example, if tun0 is the VPN interface, then do:

```
% nmap -e tun0  (plus whatever options) target_IPs
```

- -e : Use specified interface
- --iflist to list the interfaces as Nmap sees them.

Comment: Sadly, same output as if not specifying the interface...

Comment: I just tested my setup, which is: Lion + OpenVPN connecting to Linode cloud VM running CentOS.  Doing a connect() scan will work: % sudo nmap -sT -e tun0 -T5 -P0 <target_IP>  (i.e. -sT = TCP connect scan vs TCP SYN scan, avoiding raw packets).  Checking what is supported...

Answer (score 0):

**Use other scaning options**

The option ***--packet-trace*** reveals the first step of the packet, so you can be sure that you are using the interface you chose with -e

With the light from @Tate Hansen try other scan types like ***-sT -sN -sX***, those already elicited some reply from the targets.

The debug output format activated with ***-d*** proved useful to activate the debug messages (it can be overwhelming)

The VPN is a security measure that, depending on the implementation, may have some functions set up in the origin (Firewall or VPN gateway) that may block some kind of traffic by default.